# Why was the feminine pronoun 'herself' used to refer to a generic antecedent who can be male or female?

Tags: pronouns, reflexive-pronouns, gender

> The customer can serve herself, and then pay for the goods with the minimum of delay.

In the sentence, the customer can be a male or female. But the pronoun 'herself' has been used. I'm confused with the use of 'herself'. Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 15):

We don't have widely-adopted gender neutral singular pronouns. The authors are trying to avoid using **himself** to describe both genders, and so use **herself**. This is quite a common practice. Other possibilities might be to say **himself or herself**, or **customers can serve themselves**.

See this reference for plenty of [detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_and_gender-neutral_pronouns#Generic_he)

Comment: I'm not sure it's a "common practice", but it is seen increasingly. A shame that it's just as sexist as the term it purports to fix. The "themselves" suggestion is great.

Comment: According to wikipedia some writers alternate male and female pronouns too - can't say I've ever seen that in practice.

Comment: @djna I have seen it done.  An example: https://www.amazon.com/Baby-Book-Revised-Everything-About-ebook/dp/B0083EV3OC/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1

Comment: @Lightness - I think the idea is to alternate, not just always use 'herself.'

Comment: @DanBarron: It depends on the person. I know some who just use it as a "default", as a sort of protest against a perceived "default" of male pronouns in common chatter.

Comment: @djna There are many factions contending over these little pronouns. Some insist on supplanting _he_ with _she._ Some alternate the usages. Some favor forcing _they_ into service as a gender-neutral singular. Some think it's all just playing silly buggers. Some feel the use of _she_ is as sexist as the use of _he_ (although that viewpoint would be easier to justify if women had ever referred to men as _chattel_ or denied them the vote.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I've been using "themselves" my whole life as the default pronoun but that could be a carry-over from my native language (which incidentally does not have a gender specific pronoun rather it has an impersonal "it" (ia) and a personal "IT" (dia) though there is still the choice of weather to treat the 3rd person as singular or plural, I tend to pick plural as default)

Comment: Actually, "he" and "man" are gender-neutral, depending on context.

Comment: @P.E.Dant they has been singular in spoken English for six hundred years, so any forcing happened a long time ago. Though in this case it might simply be that the writer assumed that it's women who do most of the shopping.

Comment: @Agent_L: While strictly technically I concur, I decided not to mention this because colloquially this is no longer accepted as true in the general sense. Not a battle worth fighting any more ;)

Answer (score 12):

The gender-neutral pronoun is ***they / them*** (nominative / accusative), but things get a little confused with the reflexive form because not everyone is entirely happy with ***themself*** (they want to stick with ***themselves*** even in contexts where the referent is obviously singular).

To illustrate this, consider the "reflexive singular" context [*anyone can find themselves*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22anyone%20can%20find%20themselves%22), which gets 343 hits in Google Books. The more "logical" [*anyone can find themself*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22anyone%20can%20find%20themself%22) gets only 2 hits.

---

In short, unless he wants to rely on the (somewhat outdated) principle that ***he / himself*** can validly be used with no specific implication of gender, OP can "correctly" use either of ***themself / themselves***.

But it's always going to be a bit awkward, and some people might object to the specific choice (or even simply object to "singular they" on principle). So many people would simply rephrase so they don't need to make any such choice (*Self-service allows the customer to pay for the goods with the minimum of delay,* for example).

Comment: Use of "singular they" often results in a muddle of singular and plural. It is often possible to recast the sentence to a straight plural, like here one could say, "Customers can serve themselves ..." etc. But making a statement plural can also change the meaning, e.g. indicating that people are doing something as a group when the intent was to say that they are acting individually, etc.